# Making "tab control buttons" visible in layout mode

Tags: tabs, filemaker

I want to use [BackMagic](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331286551863&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.seedcode.com/cp-app/ste_cat/backmagic&ei=FdJZT7-9K4Kp0QWIrszTDQ&usg=AFQjCNH-XDVSPfuZ2VUhdsBGXcaVIhGXwQ) (to have back and forward buttons in Filemaker). In order to do this I need to name all of the tabs in my database (it wasn't built by me so currently they are not labelled). At the moment I am going through each layout and hunting for which objects/areas are tabs (as it is not always obvious what/where a tabs is)...

is there a way to make the "tab control button" visible in layout mode?

Comment: I'm thinking this *might* be a really stupid question, but I just can't find the "tab control button" for some group of tabs in my layouts! (I've clicked everywhere...)

Comment: "make sure "Object Info" is checked in FileMaker's "View" menu." Except it doesn't appear in the view menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might be hidden by setting their width to zero and clearing out their name. This is a hack to hide the tabs, so you can programmatically set them with some other widget/button.

Comment: Could you explain how you "an programmatically set them with some other widget/button"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you export the DDR (Database Design Report), you can quite easily identify all the tab controls in your solution. You can do this from FileMaker Pro Advanced (Tools -> Database Design Report...)

Analysis tools like BaseElements http://www.goya.com.au/baseelements and Inspector http://fmnexus.com/products/inspector/ can read in the exported DDR to produce detailed reports of the solution.